# Why is Hebrew written without vowels?

Tags: hebrew, vowels-nekudot, written-torah

Is there a religious explanation for writing Biblical Hebrew without vowels?

"[Was Hebrew originally written without vowels](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76844/was-hebrew-originally-written-without-vowels)" does not address the reasons for not using vowels.

Comment: The "religious"/Kabbalic analogy I know of, is that just like a person consists of the body and the souls, the language consists of the consonants (the body) and the soul (the vowels). If you're interested in more, please add a new question with these details to be explained in details.

Comment: Why *should* it have vowels?

Comment: Hah!  In changing the question to become on-topic, it made it a duplicate.  I've never done that before.....

Comment: @AlBerko. So why doesn’t Hebrew have the soul?

Comment: @JJLL Just like the human soul is experienced but not seen so are the vowels - not seen but heard.

Answer (score -3):

Because when writing on stone, or very expensive animal parchment, you want to conserve as much space as possible.

Old Hebrew and Aramaic was also written without spaces between words. This is why Aramaic later developed "ending letters," so that way one could see when some words ended because of the final/ending letter.